# Can I specify the absolute location for <entityFramework>.<providers>.<provider> in App.config

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6, devart, dll-reference

```
  <entityFramework>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="Devart.Data.Oracle" type="Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.OracleEntityProviderServices, Devart.Data.Oracle.Entity.EF6, Version=9.14.1204.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701" />
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

I am developing an add-in library for an application (ESRI ArcMap). At the same time, I would like to use EF6 as DB Accessing. My problem is that the application crashed every time when it executes `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory("Devart.Data.Oracle")` and an error is prompted as `Devart.Data.Oracle Failed to find or load the registered .Net Framework Data Provider.`

I sure that all required libraries are placed in the same folder with the main add-in DLL. However, the main application exe is not in the same place with the add-in DLL. Seems that the application load its add-in DLL by searching through the add-in folder separately.

My observation is that `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory` searches for the providers DLL only within the folder of which the exe located at. Therefore, it cannot find the provider DLL which is located in the add-in folder. May I know if there is any way to specify where should `DbProviderFactories.GetFactory` search for the provider DLL?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DbProviderFactories registration via code:

```
private static void InitDbProvFactEntry() {
  bool DevartProviderRegistered = false;
  var dataSet = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.data") as System.Data.DataSet;
  foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in dataSet.Tables[0].Rows) {
    if ((string)dr[2] == "Devart.Data.Oracle") {
      DevartProviderRegistered = true;
    }
  }
  if (!DevartProviderRegistered) {
    dataSet.Tables[0].Rows.Add("dotConnect for Oracle"
        , "Devart dotConnect for Oracle"
        , "Devart.Data.Oracle"
        ,
        "Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleProviderFactory, Devart.Data.Oracle, Version=" + Devart.Data.Oracle.ProductInfo.Version + ", Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=09af7300eec23701");
  }
}
```

Loading Devart.* assemblies from YourSubDirName:

```
 AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve;
...
    private static Assembly CurrentDomain_AssemblyResolve(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args) {

      var assemblyName = new AssemblyName(args.Name);
      if (assemblyName.Name.StartsWith("Devart.")) {
        var assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(assembly.Location);
        string newPath = Path.Combine(directory, "YourSubDirName");
        var files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(newPath);
        string targetDllName = assemblyName.Name + ".dll";
        if (files.Any(name => name.EndsWith(targetDllName))) {
          string fullFilePath = Path.Combine(newPath, targetDllName);
          return Assembly.LoadFrom(fullFilePath);
        }
      }

      return null;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. Have tried, works like a charm